# $(1+x)^n \ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ is there something wrong in my proof?

Tags: real-numbers, binomial-theorem

This problem comes from my textbook, and I think it has mistake with equality sign, but if it doesn't, please, give me some hints. Here is the problem. It asks me to show inequality by using binomial theorem

[image: main formule]

And here is my steps

[image: my job]

as [image: ex] cannot be ZERO i think there shouldn't be equality sign. maybe x should have been choosen as -1  and n=1 for example? Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: All the summands are non-negative so you have your inequality after the first step.

Comment: Yes, but the problem offers non-strict inequality

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean: $$1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2\le\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k\;,\;\;n\ge 2$$ so what's the problem? Also your inquality *must* be for $\;n\ge2\;$

Comment: the problem is that it asks from me to also prove the case [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%29^n+%3D+n%28n-1%29%2F2+*+x^2)

which doesnt exist

Comment: Who is "it" that asks you to prove something? You wrote above that you have to *show* the inequality in your title: what else? you already did that, or almost.

Comment: Now I'm more sure that this could be typo mistake. Sorry about wrong spelling of my exact problem

Answer (score 1):

It does seem that the problem was posed in a less ambitious form
than it might have been.

The only problem I can find in your proof (and it is very small and easily fixed)
is that you appear to assume implicitly that $N \geq 2.$
If $N < 2$ then you have to explain what you mean by writing $\binom n2$ in that case.

One thing you can do is prove three separate cases: $N=0,$ $N=1,$ and $N\geq 2.$
The first two cases are trivial, and then you are left with the third case
which says explicitly that $N\geq 2$ and you can obviously write $\binom n2$.

Since you can prove that a strict inequality holds, it follows that the non-strict
inequality holds as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that mistake, David. I have also checked possibility of solution of (n,x) good pair with wolfram, but it didn't give me any good results. Gotta check that third case atm

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, just observe that if $a>0$ is true then $a\geq0$ is true, in the latter you have $a=0$  $\color{red}{or}$ $a>0$.

Comment: yes, but was it necessary to put equality sign there? or I may simply ignore that fact?

Comment: @shcolf It was not necessary, but it is not wrong, so yes, you may just ignore this point:)

Comment: ah, thanks for heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Check $x=−2$ and $n$ being positive odd in the statement you are trying to prove.

Comment: I think x cannot be a negative number